# Ubuntu, libftdi priviliges, seg fault when non-root user run program

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write simple program, that uses libftdi, and I have come across a strange problem.

When running the program as non-root it looks like this:

> ./BoxDriver
> Naruszenie ochrony pamięci (zrzut pamięci)

And in Dmesg the last line I see is:

> [ 3320.467864] BoxDriver[4205]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f05c2821f7a sp 00007ffd9c6c9c00 error 4 in libftdi.so.1.20.0[7f05c2820000+7000]

I am using Ubuntu:

Linux AdamsPC 3.19.0-30-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 2 22:08:41 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

And FTDI device:

Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0403:6010 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT2232C Dual USB-UART/FIFO IC

The program runs fine, when it is running as a root:

> sudo ./BoxDriver
>
> OK, started

I have also tried to debug the source code (in eclipse ang gcc, no seg fault occurred), and the problem is with:

```
ftdi_usb_open(ftc, 0x0403, 0x6010)
```

It always returns -8, that stands for : "get product description failed"

I have searched for any answer, most are about adding user to dialout group, or adding rule to udev, but none of answers I have founded worked.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: DO you remember how you fixed this issue. I am facing same issue here

Answer (score 0):

There is a few different ways to fix this but generally it sounds like your user account does not have permission to interface with the USB device. You could add the user to the appropriate group I believe for ubuntu that is dialout so.

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout user
```

Alternatively if multiple accounts need to use it but they all should have permissions you could change the filesystem it's mounted to to have full permissions.

```
sudo chmod 777 /media/drive_name
```

Comment: I have did it, and still no result.

Comment: I am sorry, for double post, couldn't edit post after 5 mins.

I have added user to group dialout, but this did not solve my problem.
My user is also in group udev, still without result.
Also i have tried to remove modemmanager package from system, another fail.

This device in not visible at /media/  .  It is not storage device, just interface to directly cominicate device. It is this chip : [link](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT2232D.htm). 
The device is fully operational, under windows, with the same code it runs perfectly.

Comment: Ahhh ok it's a FTDI chip gotcha gotcha. First just to make sure when you add yourself to a group log out and back in for the changes to take effect. Another guess then would be looking for something like /dev/ttyUSB0 (or similar depending on how many USB devices you have) I would try basically plugging in and out and finding the difference in the /dev/ directory. Try changing the permissions of that device, this would need to be repeated each time the device is plugged in though so it's not ideal.

Comment: $ ls -l /dev/ | grep ttyUSB
crwxrwxrwx  1 root dialout 188,   0 lis  5 08:23 ttyUSB0

$ id -Gn
adams adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare

And still nothing, still -8